# Is there a tool like firebug for android hybrid apps

Tags: android, testing, automation, firebug, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi I am trying to automate some sencha and phonegap based hybrid applications... as I have access to only apk files I am unable to identify elements (links, id, name, css etc)... can you please tell me any tool with which I can work on hybrid apps...

I am using Appium as automation tool.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Appium inspector (for mac only) can help or you can also try [sendroid inspector](http://selendroid.io/inspector.html) for the same.
Another alternate is: 
You may find html assets in apk. Unzip apk and open that html file in borwser to loactate elements.

Comment: Hi @user861594, Thanks for your reply... We are working on Android apps so Appium inspector doesnt help much... also as you said we can unzip the apk to check the html assets, it does work for some apps but not for all for e.g. apps built by Sencha...